# Wave Dashboard, drill down functionality using Hyperlink

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

So, I was trying to build a **Wave Dashboard**, with widget type as Number

I can summarize my data into a step and display the step on the number widget.

> The problem that I am facing is, I am not able to drill down to the
>   data by clicking on the Number.
>
> I can use the explore option on the Number widget and allow users to
>   create a lens. But that is not what I want.

I want the number to be displayed as a hyperlink, on click of which I can view the entire table on which the summary data was obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Right now as of my understanding there is no option to click the number widget and open any think but you can achieve this by link widget and on click of that open dashboard/lens with the required table displaying data.
For number value, display it as text in button title area. You can have value change dynamically based on step

[Check this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194488/dynamic-target-bar-reference-line/198334#198334)