# Dynamic target bar/ reference line

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

Is it possible to have a dynamic target bar? What I mean by this is say depending on what filter you select, the target bar will change. So if I set a filter to 'work group', depending on what I choose the target bar will change. If it is possible how do you do something like this? Is there something like if else'?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
Yes there is a way to change the text value dynamical it may be reference line,text widget.. any thing that display text.
You do it by using

> .asString() of saql

Steps

- Create a step that results in value that you want to use

Example:

let step name be Account_1

```
q = load "Account";
q = group q by all;
q = foreach q generate count() as 'count';
q = limit q 2000;`
```

- Now in Your JSON(Toggle by Ctrl+E) of your dashboard go to widget in which you want to change the text dynamical
  replace your text with this line

  `Syntax:{{cell(<stepname>.result, <line number>, "<fieldname>").asString()}}`

Example:
For us to use row count in reference line

`"label": ":{{cell(Account_1.result, 0, "count").asString()}}"`

Now as the row count changes reference line value to changes

[Reference](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/bi_dev_guide_bindings.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can dynamically set a reference line and its label based on a measure from a step.

[Here is the relevant documentation article from the Analytics Bindings Developer Guide.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_bindings.meta/bi_dev_guide_bindings/bi_dashboard_bindings_wave_designer_set_reference_line.htm)

You can also check the live example of this binding (and many more) by installing the [Einstein Analytics Learning Adventure app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DoLB3UAN).